# How to view / open a calculator in mac OS X?

Tags: macos, operating-system, calculator

I am new to mac and am familiar with windows, I want to open a calculator in Mac. Any help?

Comment: Like opening the standard calculator app on your system??

Comment: Yes standard calculator. 'command+spacebar' and search for calc - resolved the issue.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9):

You can hit command + spacebar, which will bring up a search bar, and then type in calc, or calculator, and hit enter to open the calculator application. You can also find the calculator in Applications, or you can just use command + spacebar and type in the equation you wish to solve to the search bar, and the answer will appear without you needing to fully open the calculator app.

Comment: This is the most productive answer I have found.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make the calculator available on the dock.  This can be achieved as follows:

- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open a new Finder window
- In the left side of the Finder window select "Applications" under "Favorites"
- In the right side of the Finder window select the "Calculator" app
  [image]
- Drag the "Calculator" app to where ever you'd like on the dock

You can then click on the Calculator icon in the dock any time you want to start it.
[image]